# C++ Primer Plus Chapter 6 Exercise 2 Enter understanding

Tags: c++

I am learning from C++ Primer Plus book, and I've recently done this exercise from the book. I have a problem: when the user hits enter without any sign, then in the next entry to display any of these functions he has to hit enter again, because if not it'll still display "Wrong choice" and "Next Choice:" all the time. Can you tell me what's wrong with this code, and what should I add?
Thanks in advance.

```
        /*When you join the Benevolent Order of Programmers, you can be known at BOP
    meetings by your real name, your job title, or your secret BOP name.Write a program
    that can list members by real name, by job title, by secret name, or by a member’s
    preference. Base the program on the following structure:
    // Benevolent Order of Programmers name structure
    struct bop {
    char fullname[strsize]; // real name
    char title[strsize]; // job title
    char bopname[strsize]; // secret BOP name
    int preference; // 0 = fullname, 1 = title, 2 = bopname
    };
    In the program, create a small array of such structures and initialize it to suitable
    values. Have the program run a loop that lets the user select from different alternatives:
    a. display by name b. display by title
    c. display by bopname d. display by preference
    q. quit
    302 Chapter 6 Branching Statements and Logical Operators
    Note that “display by preference” does not mean display the preference member; it
    means display the member corresponding to the preference number. For instance, if
    preference is 1, choice d would display the programmer’s job title.A sample run
    may look something like the following:
    Benevolent Order of Programmers Report
    a. display by name b. display by title
    c. display by bopname d. display by preference
    q. quit
    Enter your choice: a
    Wimp Macho
    Raki Rhodes
    Celia Laiter
    Hoppy Hipman
    Pat Hand
    Next choice: d
    Wimp Macho
    Junior Programmer
    MIPS
    Analyst Trainee
    LOOPY
    Next choice: q
    Bye!*/
```

Solution:

```
    #include <iostream>

    void text();
    void name();
    void title();
    void secret();
    void prefr();

    const int strSize = 23;
    const int People = 4;

    char ch;

    struct bop {
    char fullname[strSize]; // real name
    char title[strSize];    // job title
    char bopname[strSize];  //secret BOP name
    int preference;         // 0 = fullname, 1 = title, 2 = bopname
    };

    bop people[People]  //array of 4 structures
        {
            {"Tony Hawk", "Junior Programmer", "Novice",2},  //first member
            {"Bill Gates", "Founder of Microsoft", "Billionaire",1},    //second member
            {"Pop Leather", "Graphic Designer", "Fast and Furious",2},  //third member
            {"Steve Jobs", "Apple Leader", "Undead Dragon",0}   //fourth member
        };


    int main()
    {
        text();    //call a text function
        std::cin.get(ch);    //get a character
        int i=0;
        while(ch!='q')
        {
            switch(ch)
            {
                case 'a':
                    name();
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    title();
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    secret();
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    prefr();
                    break;
                default: std::cout << "Wrong choice\n";
            }

            std::cout << "Next choice: \n";
            std::cin.get();
            std::cin.get(ch);
        }
        std::cout<<"Bye!";
        return 0;
    }

    void text()
    {
        std::cout<<"Benevolent Order of Programmers Report\n"
        "a. display by name         b. display by title\n"
        "c. display by bopname      d. display by preference\n"
        "q. quit\n"
        "Enter your choice:";
    }   
    void name()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<People;i++)
        std::cout<<people[i].fullname<<std::endl;
    }
    void title()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<People;i++)
        std::cout<<people[i].title<<std::endl;
    }
    void secret()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<People;i++)
            std::cout<<people[i].bopname<<std::endl;
    }
    void prefr()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<People;i++)
        {
            if(people[i].preference==0)
                std::cout<<people[i].fullname<<std::endl;
            else if(people[i].preference==1)
                std::cout<<people[i].title<<std::endl;
            else if(people[i].preference==2)
                std::cout<<people[i].bopname<<std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies here:

```
std::cin.get();
std::cin.get(ch);
```

If there was indeed a character, the first `get` will clean the newline, and the second will perform another read.

If there was no character to begin with, the first `get` will consume the actual input, and `ch` end up as a newline.

---

A solution to that is: don't treat input as valid if you're not sure it's valid. In particular, you're expecting two characters of input: any character except newline followed by newline.

There are two rather simple ways to solve your problem:

- Don't use characters: simply work on `std::string` and treat empty string as invalid.
- Check if the first character was a newline and *don't* skip an additional character then.

---

A more advanced solution would be to experiment more with functions. Could you wrap the input to return `optional<char>`? Or even better, `optional<Choice>`, where `Choice` is an `enum class`?

Or perhaps you could create a function that loops automatically, prompting for a proper input every time, and separate it from the main program logic?

Comment: I acutally don't understand the std::string method, because if I use std::string, then I can't use it in the switch.

Comment: @JerzyTuszyński Unfortunately C++ doesn't allow that, but `if.. else if ...` chain is (in this case) equivalent to that. Oooor you could store a map of pairs of `(string, a function to be ran)`. Or do what **ildjarn** suggested below.

Comment: @JerzyTuszyński : Alternatively, you can validate that it is of length 1 then use `str[0]` for the `switch`.

Comment: Thanks guys for help, it finally works as it should. I used the if(ch=='\n') method and cleared the input queue.